# how can I increase the int through a method?

Tags: java

I am new to java and I got cought in a situation which doesn't have an ending, at least for me;
Basically what I am trying to do is to increase two int through the same method but it seems that I can't figure out.

Example:

```
int health;
int mana;
```

each value will have a button near it corresponding to the actual label where the health and mana will be displayed.

```
public void upgrade(int health, int mana){
   the problem is that I don't know how to do it?
This method should be able to increase only one stat (mana or health), and it will be called on button clicked(action listener)
}
```

Please give me some insight!

Comment: **Call by value**. Inside the method you can totally mess around with the arguments. Outside the method it won't be visible!

Comment: Wrong approach. Don't try to learn Java and start with anything related to UIs. This is not meant to be rude, but obviously you don't even understand the most basic things about java. I guarantee you: your idea to create a working UI app will fail. Step back; and work through those tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ...

Comment: Everyone has ts own style of learning how to do thing. A good example of how to reach to 10? You can do 5+5, or you can do 6+4 or you can 3+3+4. As I shown, everyone has its own way. About my ideea, I already know what I have to do, the problem is that I have never tried it before, so I don't know how to build it. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have been testing things out lately to see how can I use a single method to change the values for int mana and health. I do not know if this is the right way to do it, but its working very well in my case. 
For those who maybe are looking for a practical answer, it might be useful:
   Basically I added a new int called CE, where everytime I called an upgrade, I equalizet it wiht the passing value (val).

```
public void upgrade1(int val){
            if(val < 5)
                val = val + 1;
                CE = val; 
}
```

when I clicked the button I set the mana and health (each individually) to be equal with ***CE***. From there I only had to set the mana and health value to CE. The values now can be changed particularry on their own without modifying values that are not ment to be modified.
Thanks for your support and collaboration community!

Answer (score 2):

Right... Well I got it working somehow. The problem is that, well I don't know how to set the variable to the specific int.
Here is what I have

When I call the method I use upgrade(mana);
then for the methodm I have;

```
public void upgrade(int val){
            if(val < 5)
                val = val + 1;
                setMana(val);
}
```

the value will increase.
The problem is that I also want to use this method separately for health, and I really don't know what to do next.
I have also been looking at passing by value;
Any insights, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to think Object oriented!

```
public class ManaAndHealth {
    int health;
    int mana;
    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int theHealth) {
        health=theHealth;
    }
    public void setMana(int theMana) {
        mana=theMana;
    }
    public int getMana() {
        return mana;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public void upgrade(ManaAndHealth mah){
   mah.setMana(mah.getMana()+10);
   mah.setHealth(mah.getHealth()+10);
}
```

This is just to show the concept, then other things like `maxMana` and `maxHealth` could additionally limit the upgrade ...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this is about as "object oriented" as it gets when you take some procedural code and push the "class" keyword into it. Reasonable OO looks different.

Comment: Sure, I agree, this is the way to start, and it solves the problem. Then which class takes which responsibility is a different thing and to be discussed. I could immediately write 2 more classes in order to not repeat myself etc, and I personally would go this way. But when I start putting more concepts than this basic one, I would blow up the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Java method calls use "call by value" argument passing.

Let's neglect non-primitive types where a reference is passed (also by value).
Let's only look at primitive types:

```
class Example{
    int field1 = 0;

    void method1( int arg1 )
    {
         arg1 = 5;
    }

    void method2()
    {
         field1 = 5;
    }

    void driver()
    {
         method1(field1); // <= (a copy of) the _value_ of field1 will be
                          // passed to method1. The value of field1 will
                          // stay the same, no matter what happens inside method1.
         // field1 == 0 
         method2(); // uses the class's field => change will be visible
         // field1 == 5
    }
}
```

If you use the same name like `void method1( int field1 )` it only hides the class field inside the method. Changes will still be locally visible, only.